# Tensor product restriction of scalars and isomorphism

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $S\subset R$ a subring. Let $M$ and $N$ be two $R$-modules.

1) Via restriction of scalars, we can also view $M$ and $N$ as $S$-modules. Show that we have a surjective homomorphism $\phi:M\otimes_S N\to M\otimes_R N,m\otimes n\mapsto m\otimes n$. Describe its kernel.

2) Let $R=\Bbb C[x]/(x^3)$. Consider $M=\Bbb C\oplus \Bbb C$ as $R$-module by $Xe_1=e_2$ and $Xe_2=0$. Prove that $$M\otimes_R M\cong M.$$

---

For (1), by definition of the tensor product, the map $M\times N\to M\otimes_R N,(m,n)\mapsto m\otimes n$ is $R$-bilinear. As $S\subset R$ is a subring, it is also $S$-bilinear, so the universal property gives a homomorphism $M\otimes_S N\to M\otimes_R N,m\otimes n\mapsto m\otimes n$. The fact that it is surjective seems trivial to me by the formula, but I feel like I am wrong. For the kernel, I have no idea.

(2) Should this be a consequence of (1)? I tried to use the universal property.

Could anybody help?

Comment: Surjectivity is trivial. For the kernel, perhaps you could benefit from the viewpoint that the tensor product of two modules is “the most free” product module one can form such that one has linearity in each entry with respect to scalars. Therefore, viewing an element tensored over R gives exactly the extra requirement that one must now have bilinearity with respect to R\S. Therefore an element gets mapped to zero if and only if this requirement forces it to be zero in M tensored with N over R. In other words, the fact that you can move scalars of R\S between entries must somehow

Comment: Force the element to become zero

Comment: Then it becomes beneficial to ask yourself the following: when forming the tensor product which expressions of the form n tensor m over R are equivalent to zero. For instance clearly if either m or n is zero then their tensor product is zero. Can you think of a more general situation?